# Laravel Auth::attempt works and then Auth::check fails

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authentication, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have been following the tutorials on authentication but something isn't working. Auth::attempt seems to work properly. When it fails I get redirected back to login with errors and when it succeeds I get redirected to my blog index. Sadly, after that I can't get to any of the protected pages! I simply am redirected right back to my login page. It's making me crazy!

I dumped some variables in the blog index view that renders when Auth::attempt is successful to see what's going on:

```
@section('content')
<h1>This is a blog!!</h1>

<?php
    echo var_dump(Session::all());
    echo var_dump(Auth::check());
    foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
        <div class="post">
        <?php
            echo "<h3><a href=\"/blog/$post->slug\">{$post->title}</a></h3>";
            echo "{$post->content}";
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
@stop
```

When I var_dump Session::all() I get this array:

```
array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "0hqRso6my0VpvQVtrXlLDeKioglu4xNXl5pbpNGM" ["flash"]=> array(2) { ["old"]=> array(0) { } ["new"]=> array(0) { } } ["url"]=> array(1) { ["intended"]=> string(49) "http://temporal-storm-743.appspot.com/blog/create" } ["login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc"]=> NULL }
```

And when I var dump Auth::check I get false: bool(false)

I'm going to assume the NULL after login_ur4iafo9awhatever means the session hasn't successfully logged the user in?

I haven't changed the auth filter which I am applying to the protected pages from the default in filters.php.

I've checked my session.php file:

```
'driver' => 'memcached',
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

and my auth.php

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => 'User',
```

and my model....

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

  use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $table   = 'WebUser';
  protected $primaryKey   = 'WebUserId';
  protected $hidden   = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

and of course my login controller method:

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|min:8'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if( $validator->fails() )
        return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::except('password'))->withErrors($validator);

    $userdata = array(
        'email'=>Input::get('email'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password'),
    );

    if ( !Auth::attempt($userdata, true) )
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['email'=>'Login failed.']);

   return Redirect::to('blog');
}
```

I have no idea what's going on you guys.

**EDIT:** I have some idea of what's going on now, you guys.

I came back to this problem after a vacation and started poking around in the authentication files and forums and tried a few different auth methods. I got the authentication working!

I am still not 100% sure why, but the Eloquent driver doesn't seem to work on Google App Engine. After changing from Eloquent to database authentication, updating my database so that all of the primary keys are set to id and adding `remember_token VARCHAR(100) NULL` as a field things seem to be authenticating just fine.

Maybe someone with more Laravel experience and more of an understanding of how the different providers and authentication work can help me understand why only database Authentication works on Google app engine?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is any errors within your logs?

Comment: As you are remembering the login this could lead you to your solution [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26) as these methods are required to remember the user as being logged in. As well as the remember_token field in the users table.

Comment: Thanks guys!
I added the remember_token field to the database and used it successfully with auth.basic. Will try adding those methods and see if that helps with auth. Also tried passing false for the remember param and had the same errors so I don't think that's the issue.

Logs are error free.

Comment: The methods are within the Interface and are required to work. Add them to the model and try `Auth::attempt` again

Comment: Still getting the same false result from Auth::check() :(

Comment: you can check if the credentials you logged in was saved in session by trying to dump: Auth::user()->email

Comment: You didn't show where you use `Auth::check()`. There is none in `doLogin` method. If it's in `blog` method you should show its code.

Comment: Added the var_dump code from the view that renders after a successful auth attempt. Also tried var_dumping the Auth::user()->email and get a trying to access property of non-object. Just dumped Auth::user() instead and it's NULL. :(

I feel like once this is all said and done it's going to be a misnamed variable or something silly like that.

Answer (score 2):

I had te same issue and searched for a solution for hours.

Then I changed:

```
if(Auth::check()) return Redirect::to("/admin");
```

To:

```
if( ! Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to("/admin");
```

That worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think Laravel has a bug. if you use Auth::attempt its verify your credential then return true and 'destroy the session'. So we redirect our url and use Auth::check() so its return false. because session is destroy and you lost you data to check.